# When I did res.json (newschema), the properties are not displayed anymore on Postman

Tags: node.js, web

When I did res.json (newschema) on post action, the properties are not displayed any more on Postman and also in Mongodb.

**This is formations.routes**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Formation = require('../models/formations');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const config = require('../config/database');





router.get('/', function(req, res){
//Formation.getFormations(function(err, formations){
   // if(err)throw err;
  //  res.json(formations);
//});
Formation.find({})
.exec(function(err, Formations){
    if(err){
        console.log('error'); 
    }else{
        res.json(Formations);
    }
})
});



router.post('/', function(req, res){
    console.log('post a formations');
    var newFormation = new Formation();
    newFormation.title = req.body.title;
    newFormation.url = req.body.url;
    newFormation.description = req.body.description;
    newFormation.save(function(err, newFormation){
        if(err){
            console.log('error insertion');
        } else {
            res.json(newFormation);
            //res.json({success: true, msg:'user registred'});
        }
    });
});
```

**This is formation.models**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const config = require('../config/database');


const FormationSchema = mongoose.Schema ({
    title:  String,
    url: String,
    description:  String



});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Formation', FormationSchema, 'Formations');
```

**This is my app.js ( endpoint)**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const passport = require('passport');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('./config/database');

const User = require('./models/user');
const Formation = require('./models/formations');



mongoose.connect(config.database ,  { useNewUrlParser: true });
mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
console.log('connected to database... ' + config.database);
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
console.log('database error'+err);
});




/*mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/hello', { useNewUrlParser: true });
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
    console.log('we are connected!');

});*/



const app = express();
const users = require('./routes/users');
const formations = require('./routes/formations');

//port number
 const port = 3001;

//cors middleware
 app.use(cors({
     origin: 'http://localhost:4200'
 }));
 //passwport middelware
 app.use(passport.initialize());
 app.use(passport.session());
 require('./config/passport')(passport); //pour implémenter fichier passport.js

 //set static folder
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public')));




//BodyParser middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/users', users);//hedhiya ki nekteb /users barka f url yemchili direct lel const users = require('./routes/users'); fichier hedhka

app.use('/formations', formations); 

//c un route 
//just meloul 7atineha bch ntastiw beha 
//index route
 app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('invalid endpoint');
});



//start Server
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

 app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server started on port' +port);
 });
```

**And this is how I make a post action in Postman**

[image: postman screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `save` method only has an `error` parameter in the callback. You are adding a newFormations parameter which will always be undefined and in the scope of the method you are returning undefined in the res.json call. To fix it remove the newFormation parameter as below:

```
newFormation.save(function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log('error insertion');
    } else {
        res.json(newFormation);
        //res.json({success: true, msg:'user registred'});
    }
});
```